# Angular Material issue in IE11

Tags: html, css, flexbox, angular-material

I am having trouble showing this datepicker in IE-11,

This is how it looks like in chrome,

[image]

AND This is how it looks like in IE-11

[image]

One of the issue is with angular material css class `.md-select-label` min-width... which is set to 64px changing it to 90px fix one of my issue but that's not it as not sure how to show calendar dates properly.

Here is the codepen of it - http://codepen.io/alenaksu/pen/eNzbrZ

Comment: As  per knowledge it is issue of `[layout-wrap] {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}` which seems not work in IE11.

Comment: @ketan thanks, is there anyway I could overcome this issue as i only want this to work in IE atm

Comment: Issue has been resolved and updated on Codepen by submitter, I am going to go through it to find out what has been changed later on, thanks

Comment: What changes you done to resolved?